# How to show the second ListView based on the selected value in the first ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, sqldatasource

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I have to create a quiz engine application. I am using three LiveView controls to show:
quiz information
question information (based on the selected quiz on the first ListView)
answers information (based on the selected question on the second ListView)

I have the following database design:

```
QuizContent Table: ID, QuizID, QuestionID, AnswerID
Quiz Table: QuizID, Title, Description
Question Table: QuestionID, Question, QuestionOrder, AnswerExplanation
Answers Table: AnswerID, Answer
```

What I want now is the following: when the user (who is the Admin) comes to the Quiz Engine Page, he should only see the first ListView which is mainly about the Quiz Information. And when he selects one of the quizzes, the second ListView will be displayed with the Question information of that selected quiz. And when he selects one of the questions, the third ListView will be displayed with the answers information of that selected question.

**So how to do that?**

I know I should not post too much code or information, but I have to do it to make it clear:

```
<div align="center">
            <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="QuizID" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" >

                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="">
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="UpdateButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/update24.png" ToolTip="Update"  runat="server" CommandName="Update" />

                            <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/cancel324.png" ToolTip="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="DescriptionTextBox" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <table id="Table1" runat="server" style="">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                No data was returned.</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="">
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="InsertButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/add24.png" ToolTip="Add"  runat="server" CommandName="Insert" />

                            <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/clear24.png" ToolTip="Cancel"  runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                        </td>

                        <%--<td>
                            &nbsp;</td>--%>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="DescriptionTextBox" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="">
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="Delete"  runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                            <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit"  runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />

                            <asp:ImageButton ID="SelectButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/select.png" ToolTip="Select"  runat="server" CommandName="Select" />
                            <%--<asp:Button ID="SelectButton" runat="server" CommandName="Select" Text="Select" />--%>
                        </td>
                        <%--<td>
                            <asp:Label ID="QuizIDLabel" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("QuizID") %>' />
                        </td>--%>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <div ><table id="thetable" width="97%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; border:2px solid #003366; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="background-color:#C6D7B5;">
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">...</th>
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Title</th>
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Description</th>
                            </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody><tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr></tbody>
                    </table></div>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <SelectedItemTemplate>
                    <tr style="">
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                            <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                        </td>
                        <%--<td>
                            <asp:Label ID="QuizIDLabel" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("QuizID") %>' />
                        </td>--%>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </SelectedItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QuizSysDBConnectionString %>" 

                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Quiz]" 
                DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Quiz] WHERE [QuizID] = @QuizID" 
                InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Quiz] ([Title], [Description]) VALUES (@Title, @Description)" 


                UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Quiz] SET [Title] = @Title, [Description] = @Description WHERE [QuizID] = @QuizID">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="QuizID" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Description" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="QuizID" Type="Int32" />
                </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>

    <br /><br />

    <%--Second ListView that will contain the content of the quiz--%>
    <div align="center">
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
            DataKeyNames="QuestionID" InsertItemPosition="LastItem">

            <EditItemTemplate>

                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="UpdateButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/update24.png" ToolTip="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/cancel324.png" ToolTip="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <%--<td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionIDLabel1" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>' />
                    </td>--%>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="QuestionTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("Question") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="QuestionOrderTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("QuestionOrder") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerExplanationTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("AnswerExplanation") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </EditItemTemplate>

            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table runat="server" 
                    style="">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            No data was returned.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>

            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="InsertButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/add24.png" ToolTip="Add" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/clear24.png" ToolTip="Cancel"  runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <%--<td>
                        &nbsp;</td>--%>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="QuestionTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("Question") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="QuestionOrderTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("QuestionOrder") %>'/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerExplanationTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("AnswerExplanation") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </InsertItemTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="SelectButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/select.png" ToolTip="Select" runat="server" CommandName="Select" />
                            <%--<asp:Button ID="SelectButton" runat="server" CommandName="Select" Text="Select" />--%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionOrderLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("QuestionOrder") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerExplanationLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("AnswerExplanation") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div ><table id="thetable" width="97%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; border:2px solid #003366; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="background-color:#C6D7B5;">
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">...</th>
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Question</th>
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Question Order</th>
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Answer Explanation</th>
                            </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody><tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr></tbody>
                    </table></div>     
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionOrderLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("QuestionOrder") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerExplanationLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("AnswerExplanation") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        </div>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QuizSysDBConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Question]"

            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Question] WHERE [QuestionID] = @QuestionID" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Question] ([Question], [QuestionOrder], [AnswerExplanation]) VALUES (@Question, @QuestionOrder, @AnswerExplanation)" 


            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Question] SET [Question] = @Question, [QuestionOrder] = @QuestionOrder, [AnswerExplanation] = @AnswerExplanation WHERE [QuestionID] = @QuestionID">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="QuestionID" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Question" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="QuestionOrder" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="AnswerExplanation" Type="String" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView1" Name="QuizID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Question" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="QuestionOrder" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="AnswerExplanation" Type="String" />
                </UpdateParameters>

            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView1" Name="QuizID" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <br /><br />

    <%--Third ListView that will contain the content of the quiz--%>
    <div align="center">
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView3" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" 
            DataKeyNames="AnswerID" InsertItemPosition="LastItem">

            <EditItemTemplate>

                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="UpdateButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/update24.png" ToolTip="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/cancel324.png" ToolTip="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <%--<td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerIDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AnswerID") %>' />
                    </td>--%>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("Answer") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </EditItemTemplate>

            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table runat="server" 
                    style="">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            No data was returned.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>

            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="InsertButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/add24.png" ToolTip="Add" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/clear24.png" ToolTip="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <%--<td>
                        &nbsp;</td>--%>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("Answer") %>'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </InsertItemTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                    </td>
                    <%--<td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AnswerID") %>' />
                    </td>--%>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Answer") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div ><table id="thetable" width="97%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; border:2px solid #003366; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="background-color:#C6D7B5;">
                            <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">...</th>
                            <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Answer</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody><tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr></tbody>
                </table></div>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("Answer") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        </div>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QuizSysDBConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Answers] WHERE QuestionID = @QuestionID"

            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Answers] WHERE [AnswerID] = @AnswerID" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Answers] ([Answer]) VALUES (@Answer)" 


            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Answers] SET [Answer] = @Answer WHERE [AnswerID] = @AnswerID">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="AnswerID" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Answer" Type="String" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView2" Name="QuestionID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Answer" Type="String" />
                </UpdateParameters>

            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView2" Name="QuestionID" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**NOTE:**
I don't have any code-behind.

**UPDATE:**

The problem is as following: when I run the code, I will see the three ListView controls. It should show only one of them. Also, with showing all the ListView controls, even if I selected one of the quizzes in the first ListView, I will still see the same content in the second and third ListView controls which are not related to the selected quiz in the first ListView and I don't know why.

UPDATE #2:
Now, it works with me but I don't know why I am getting the set of questions of that selected quiz twice (repeated) in the second ListView as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Try adding `Distinct` to your select queries: `SELECT distinct ....`

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your continuous help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, since you already have code like this:

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView1" Name="QuizID" 
        PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
</SelectParameters>
```

That's all the code needed to bind one ListView from another one

Your problem is that you have at least two`UpdatePanels`, an update panel is a control to allow **partial rendering** on your page. Which means that **by default, only the controls under the update panel will refresh** when asynchronous post backs occurs.

What you need to do is connect the three `UpdatePanels` to force refresh between them. In order to do it, you need to add triggers to your panels:

In your `UpdatePanel1` panel add:

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ListView1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
```

In your `UpdatePanel2` panel add:

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ListView2" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
```

Basically add as a trigger the parent `ListView.SelectedIndexChanged`

### Edit 1

Well according to your comments your queries are wrong

This is an example how I think it should look:

**SqlDataSource2**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QuizSysDBConnectionString %>" 
   SelectCommand="SELECT [Question].* FROM [Question] INNER JOIN [QuizContent] ON [QuizContent].[QuizID] = @QuizID"
```

**SqlDataSource3**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QuizSysDBConnectionString %>" 
   SelectCommand="SELECT [Answers].* FROM [Answers] INNER JOIN [QuizContent].QuestionID = @QuestionID"
```

I think these queries should work. To be honest your design is not traditional, the same design wouldn't contain a `QuizContent` table (perhaps I'm missing something). A traditional design for this problem would look like:

```
Quiz Table: QuizID, Title, Description
Question Table: QuestionID, QuizID, Question, QuestionOrder, AnswerExplanation
Answers Table: AnswerID, QuestionID, Answer
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it is still not working and I don't know why. Is it because all of them are mapped in the QuizContent table?

Comment: What's the exact problem? I would suggest you to remove the update panels to track down the problem

Comment: The problem is as following: when I run the code, I will see the three ListView controls. It should show only one of them. Also, with showing all the ListView controls, even if I selected one of the quizzes in the first ListView, I will still see the same content in the second and third ListView controls which are not related to the selected quiz in the first ListView and I don't know why.

Comment: mmm I just found something, in your last two `SqlDataSource` objects you have: `SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Answers]">` you do declare a select parameter **but you are not using it, therefore your lists will show always the same data**, try with this snippet: `SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Answers] where QuestionID = @QuestionID">`

Comment: I got the following error: Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'QuestionID'.

Why? Could you please have a look at my database design?

Comment: I just edited my answer. Please let me know if that worked for you

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got only the following error because of your second query in the SqlDataSource3: Incorrect syntax near '='

Comment: I think the correct query should be like this `SELECT [Answers].* FROM [Answers] INNER JOIN [QuizContent] ON [QuizContent].QuestionID = @QuestionID`

Comment: Could you please see my updated question? I am facing a strange error and I don't know if it is related to my question or something else.